# Submitting a dynamically created form in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am trying to submit a form that I dynamically created.  I am using the .submit, but it is not working.  Here is my code

```
var $message = $('.message');



$message.submit(function(e){
    console.log("Test");
});


$(document.body).on('click','.button', function(e) { 
    console.log($(this).val());
    var $input = '';
    $input = $('<p>Chat with '+$(this).val()+'</p>');
    $input.append('<div class = "chat" style="height:200px"></div>');
    $input.append('<form class="message">');
    $input.append('<input size = "35" class="messages">');
    $input.append("<br><input type='submit' class='send_message' value = 'Send' />");
    $input.append('</form>');

    $input.appendTo($("#contentWrap"));
 });
```

The code for document.body created the form.  However, when I click the submit button nothing happens.

I also tried

```
$('#contentWrap').on("submit", ".message", function(e){
            console.log("Test")
});
```

$(parent).on(event, child, function) is what most of the posts I read say to do.  However, I must be doing something else wrong.

Here is the fill front end code in js fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/55Ln0wgu/

Comment: Use `$('#contentWrap").on("submit", ".message", ...)`

Comment: I tried $('#contentWrap').on("submit", ".message", function(e){
   console.log("Test")
  });   Still does not print out Test

Comment: Is all your code inside `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: `$input.append('</form>');` is fundamentally wrong.

Comment: *"However, when I click the submit button nothing happens."* are you sure the page isn't reloading after posting to the server? because that's what it should be doing. If you're not paying close attention you might not even notice it.

Comment: @KevinB wouldn't the console.log print out?

Comment: It would, but then it would almost instantly go away unless you have the preserve log checkbox checked.

Comment: @KevinB I added e.preventDefault();, to make sure the page is reloading.  However, that did not fix the problem

Comment: In the log with that checkbox checked, do you see "navigating to <x>" in the console after submitting?

Comment: Also, to be clear, your "i also tried" portion is the correct way, your original way won't work.

Comment: @KevinB are you talking about the preserve log checkbox?

Comment: Yes, the preserve log checkbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `submit` button isn't in the form. You're appending each `<input>` element to the `<p>`, not the `<form>`. The result is equivalent to this HTML, which has an empty `<form>`.

```
<p>Chat with 
    <div class="chat" style="height:200px"></div>
    <form class="message"></form>
    <input size="35" class="messages"><br>
    <input type="submit" class="send_message" value="Send">
</p>
```

Remember, `.append()` operates on the DOM hierarchy, it's not concatenating strings to the HTML.

Your code would work if you built `$input` as a string.

You also need to use event delegation for the Submit button, since it's being added dynamically.

```js
$(document.body).on('click', '.button', function(e) {
  console.log($(this).val());
  var $input = '<p>Chat with ' + $(this).val();
  $input += '<div class = "chat" style="height:200px"></div>';
  $input += '<form class="message">';
  $input += '<input size = "35" class="messages">';
  $input += "<br><input type='submit' class='send_message' value = 'Send' />";
  $input += '</form></p>';

  $("#contentWrap").append($input);
});

$('#contentWrap').on("submit", ".message", function(e) {
  alert("Test");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Form should appear here:
<div id="contentWrap">

</div>
Chat with:
<input type="button" class="button" value="Fred">
<input type="button" class="button" value="Joe">
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$('#contentWrap').on('click', '.button', function(e) { 
    console.log($(this).val());   `
```

Comment: It does not seem to change anything

Comment: This is in the code that creates the form, he said that this part works. His problem is with the code that submits the form.